# How to check if the connection to a SFTP server is successful using WinSCP in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, connection, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have sent a file by SFTP to another server using WinSCP in VB.NET.

I would like to see if the connection was successful or not.

I also need to know if the file already exists in the directory beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do.  You can create a session log that tells you (in a LOT of detail) what happened during your file transfer.  You can also put a try-catch block around `mySession.Open(mySessionOptions)` to catch an error.

Finally, use `mySession.FileExists(remotepath)` to check to see if the file is already on the server.

```
Dim mySessionOptions As New SessionOptions
With mySessionOptions
    .Protocol = Protocol.Sftp
    .HostName = "999.999.999.999"
    .UserName = "login"
    .Password = "mypassword"
    .SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-dss 1024 99:87:99:4d:99:a3:99:b9:99:15:99:f2:99:87:88:b2"
End With

Using mySession As Session = New Session
    ' Will continuously report progress of synchronization
    AddHandler mySession.FileTransferred, AddressOf FileTransferred

    ' Connect
    mySession.SessionLogPath = "C:\Users\yourName\yourFolder\Sessionlog.log"

    'Use Try-Catch to check for error in connection
    Try
         mySession.Open(mySessionOptions)
    Catch ex As Exception
         MessageBox.show(ex.Message)
         mySession.Close()
         Exit Sub
    End Try

    'Check to see if file exist already on server
    If mySession.FileExists(remotePath) Then
           MessageBox.Show("File Exists on Server")
           mySession.Close()
           Exit Sub
    End If

    mySession.PutFiles("C:\Users\yourName\yourFolder\yourfile.dat", remotePath)

    mySession.Close()

End Using
```

Remember to check the log you created to see exactly what happened.

Comment: You also need to test if the `PutFiles` succeeded or not. Use `.Check()` for that. For example: `mySession.PutFiles("C:\Users\yourName\yourFolder\yourfile.dat", remotePath).Check()`. See [Capturing results of operations](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session#results).